# MySQLi multi_query next_result always returns 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a simple stored procedure in MySQL. Here it's code.

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'chl.rontel.ru' PROCEDURE `test`()
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
begin
    select * from `mbus_log` where serial_num='12';
    select count(*) from mbus_log;
end;
```

In SQL manager for MySQL it returns 6 rows table and total number of rows - 293.
So I want to get this values from PHP. Here is PHP code:

```
    public $mysqli;

...
    $this->mysqli=new mysqli($this->mysql_host,$this->mysql_user,$this->mysql_password,$this->mysql_db);
    if ($this->mysqli->connect_error) 
    {
        die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    $this->mysqli->query("SET NAMES UTF8");
...
        $result= $this->mysqli->multi_query("call test();");
        $getReadingsByAddress=$this->mysqli->store_result();
        if ($this->mysqli->errno) 
        {
            die('Select Error (' . $mysqli->errno . ') ' . $mysqli->error);
        }
        else
        {
            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_object($getReadingsByAddress) )
            { 
                 $res.="<tr><td><a class='serialLink' href='./'>".$row->serial_num."</a></td><td>".$row->value."</td></tr>"; 
            } 
        }
        $getReadingsByAddress->close();
        $res.=$this->mysqli->next_result();
```

$mysqli->store_result() works fine and returns correct values, but next_result method returns 1 every time. I also tried to do like this:

```
$result= $this->mysqli->multi_query("call test(); SELECT COUNT(*) from mbus_log;");
```

next result also returns 1. Also when I try `var_dump($this->mysqli->next_result());` It returns bool(false), however more_results method returns true What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Only idea I have is to try giving count(*) a column name IE count(*) AS MyCount.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: the problem is that I didn't understand principle of work of mysqli->next result.
Here is right way as it is in docs:

```
    $result= $this->mysqli->multi_query("call test();");
    if ($result)
    {
        do
        {
           $getReadingsByAddress=$this->mysqli->store_result();
           var_dump($getReadingsByAddress);
            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_object($getReadingsByAddress) )
            { 
                var_dump($row);
            } 

        if (!$this->mysqli->more_results()) 
        {
             break;
        }
        if (!$this->mysqli->next_result()) 
        {
             // report error
            break;
        }
        } while (true);
    }
```